# Вывод картинки на принтерную печать с Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, печать, принтер

Как заставить unity работать с принтером? Стоковый способ с использованием библиотеки `System.Drawing` не работает.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку картинка (сохраненная на диске) выводилась на печать на принтер

Comment: Причём тут вообще unity? Это игровой движёк, а не офисный комбаин. Ищи C# библиотеку для печати.

Comment: Этой библиотекой считается Sysdem.Drawing, и юнити не работает с ней. Поэтому и был предложен следующий вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в документации понял, что Unity не умеет работать с принтерами и научить не получится(по крайней мере у меня), поэтому пришел к такому варианту:

Пишем всю работу с принтером на WinForm, [сохраняем все данные в файл](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184970/how-to-save-printdocument-printersettings-in-a-file-so-that-user-have-not-to-se), после при каждом обращении читаем данные принтера с файла и печатаем с нужными данными.

В скипт на Unity добавляем библиотеку `System.Diagnostics` и используем простейшую функцию для открытия екзешника.

```
public void OpenExe(string SceneName)
{
   Process.Start("your\\path\\printing.exe");
}
```